# i dont know why i cant edit my array on my code

Tags: python

this is for my code function code

```
def edit():
    i()
    indeks = input(" masukan hobi ke :")
    if int(indeks)>len(hobi):
        print("data tidak ada ")
    elif int (indeks) <= len(hobi):
        hobibaru=input("hobi baru :)
        hobi[indeks]=hobibaru
```

this is my error comm

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\murtadho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\x.py", line
>   74, in 
>       show_menu()   File "C:\Users\murtadho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\x.py", line
>   62, in show_menu
>       edit_data()   File "C:\Users\murtadho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\x.py", line
>   33, in edit_data
>       buku[indeks] = judul_baru TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Whats `i`??????

Comment: And whats `hobi`...

Comment: The last line of your error message says it all. `indeks` is a string (hence why you had to cast it in the if block). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC try:

```
def edit():
    i()
    indeks = input(" masukan hobi ke :")
    if int(indeks)>len(hobi):
        print("data tidak ada ")
    elif int (indeks) <= len(hobi):
        hobibaru=input("hobi baru :")
        hobi[int(indeks)]=hobibaru
```

I can't guarantee that it would work, but it sounds reasonable and I expect it to work.

Comment: @daffafaiz I simply change `indeks` on the line `hobi[indeks]=hobibaru` to an integer using `int(...)`, so it becomes: `hobi[int(indeks)]=hobibaru`, and that's it, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a couple of issues:

You're getting input and trying to typecast it into an int.  While you maybe sure of it being an integer, it may lead towards issues if a string is inserted.

```
def edit():
    i()
    indeks = input(" masukan hobi ke :")
    try:
        indeks = int(indeks)
    except:
        break
    if indeks >len(hobi):
        print("data tidak ada ")
    elif indeks <= len(hobi):
        hobibaru=input("hobi baru :")
        hobi[indeks]=hobibaru
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should return your input `indeks` to `int` before work with `list`

```py
def edit():
    i()
    indeks = int(input(" masukan hobi ke :"))
    if indeks>len(hobi):
        print("data tidak ada ")
    elif indeks <= len(hobi):
        hobibaru=input("hobi baru :)
        hobi[indeks]=hobibaru
```